# VSCode change debug shell to bash on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, bash, visual-studio-code

**Context:** I recently switched from Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code to test the debugging functionalities of the Microsoft text editor. The main problem here is that my Ruby on Rails environment is set on bash in Ubuntu on Windows.

I changed the integrated terminal shell to bash, so, I can use the integrated terminal to launch/debug my application. But when using the integrated debug tool using the Ruby extension ( https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby ), it seems to launch the windows cmd to execute the configuration:

> Debugger terminal error: Process failed: spawn rdebug-ide.bat ENOENT

**Question:** Is my problem caused by `vscode` trying to use the windows cmd instead of the specified bash shell? If so, is there a way to tell `vscode` to use it instead of the windows cmd?

Here's my `launch.json` config for the task I want to execute :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Rails server",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "/mnt/c/Repos/<project_name>",
      "program": "rails",
      "pathToRDebugIDE": 
"~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide",
      "args": ["server"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think running VSCode on WSL works yet unless you're using a recent (as of this posting) Windows Insider build. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2760 There looks to be some (very) recent work on it from the VSCode side: https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/336

Answer (score 0):

That Ruby extension of Visual Studio Code is only able to use cmd to launch the debugger. Therefore you need a .cmd wrapper to call rdebug-ide.

Installing the RubyDevKit for Windows should provide the necessary wrappers, but you can also use the lines below.
It basically looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@ruby.exe "%~dpn0" %*
```

(This will use the ruby.exe in your PATH to execute the script named like the .bat file, but without the extension.)

Put this in the same location as rdebug-ide and call it *rdebug-ide.bat*.
Adjust your launch.json so that *pathToRDebugIDE* points to this .bat file (use the full Windows path), and make sure ruby is in your PATH.

I'm currently using this setup with a cygwin installation of ruby, rdebug-ide, rails etc.

Comment: Can you share your launch,json? Thanks!