# Configuring VS Code to use ruby debugger on WSL

Tags: ruby, rubygems, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ruby-debug-ide

I'm relatively new to using a terminal and programming in general. Here's the error I'm currently getting when hitting the 'start debugging' button is VS Code:

> Debugger terminal error: Process failed: spawn
>   ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rdebug-ide.bat ENOENT

My setup is bash on ubuntu (WSL) on Win10 10.0.16299. I have the VS Code 1.21.1 integrated terminal set up to use zsh.

Here's the steps I've taken so far:

1. installed the ruby extension for VS Code
2. inside VS Code integrated terminal, I ran `gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.7.0.beta3`
3. `gem install debase -v 0.2.2`
4. According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956983/vscode-change-debug-shell-to-bash-on-windows), I created a .bat file at `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rdebug-ide.bat`
5. added this to my launch.json inside vs code for the debuggers:

> {
>
> ```
>         "name": "Debug Local File",
>         "type": "Ruby",
>         "request": "launch",
>         "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
>         "program": "${file}",
>         "pathToRDebugIDE": "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rdebug-ide.bat",
> ```
>
> },

It seems that I might need to use the actual windows path of rdebug-ide.bat instead of the WSL path, but I've heard that it's bad to root around inside the WSL folder on windows. I figured I'd ask here first in case I'm taking the wrong steps to fix this, or if using the actual windows path might mess things up.

Comment: Did you get it working?  I'm struggling now, I get `Debugger terminal error: Process failed: spawn rdebug-ide ENOENT`, but your config file doesn't look like mine.